# Item level permission for groups

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, permissions, groups, item

I have created a SP list.  I want users in a group to be able to see/edit the list items created by others in their group but not see items created by users in a different group.  With item-level permission, I can restrict users access to items that they created but I cannot get them access to items that others in their group created.  Is there a solution for group permission at the item level?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a solution for group permission at the item level?**

- Assign this group to each item level manually. I know it's a boring practice.
- Or Develop an Event Receiver to assign this group to the item once it added based on your rules!!.
- Or use a 3rd party tool like [info wise](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/products.aspx)
- Or in case you have a little number of groups, you can add a new column to your list that holds the group name, then create a view for every group filtered by group name, then add a list view to a page with permission assigned to this group.